# To create feedback, does the peak to peak amplitude of a signal loop have to have an amplification factor (gain) that reaches zero?

Tags: amplitude, feedback

> In technical terms, feedback occurs when the gain in the signal loop
> reaches "unity" (0dB gain).

[How to Eliminate Feedback](https://www.mediacollege.com/audio/howto/feedback.html)

> Peak-to-peak amplitude (abbreviated p–p) is the change between peak
> (highest amplitude value) and trough (lowest amplitude value, which
> can be negative).

[Amplitude - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude)

Does that mean that, to create feedback, the signal's *peak to peak amplitude* must reach unity gain? Or must only some component of the signal undergo at least unity gain, perhaps some bandwidth (or recurring signal element, if that makes sense)?

I thought the former, but I think I just proved that wrong by trial and error IRL.

Comment: I ran a signal through a pedal that a scope said was decreasing ptp amplitude, then used that pedal and nothing else to process a feedback loop... and got feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In technical terms, feedback occurs when the gain in the signal loop reaches "unity" (0dB gain).

Correct.

> Peak-to-peak amplitude (abbreviated p–p) is the change between peak (highest amplitude value) and trough (lowest amplitude value, which can be negative).

Also correct but has absolutely nothing to do with the feedback.

Feedback occurs when the output of a system is fed back (as the name implies) into the input of a system. If the total round trip gain is larger than 1, feedback occurs.

Let's look at a simple example: a microphone hooked up to a loudspeaker. Sound that gets into the microphone gets amplified and played back from the loudspeaker. The sound radiated from the loudspeaker is picked up by the microphone, amplified and sent to the loudspeaker, etc. This creates a loop.

If the gain from the mic to the loudspeaker multiplied with the gain from the loudspeaker to the microphone is larger than 1, the signal gets larger at every round trip through the loop until it hits some non-linear limit. That's feedback.

In reality this a little more complicated (depends on frequency and phase as well), but that's the high level mechanism: Feedback occurs when the closed-loop gain is larger than 1. The amplitude of the input is irrelevant: a microphone will feedback even if there is no input signal at all.

> To create feedback, does the peak to peak amplitude of a signal loop ...

That question is somewhat non-sensical. The loop is a system and doesn't have an amplitude: it only as a transfer function. The type of things that have amplitude are signals. A system (like a microphone or loudspeaker) produces on output signal from an input signal but it's not a signal itself.

Comment: ok i get that, thanks. Is the gain of *signals* the same thing as changes to peak to peak amplitude?

Comment: I guess this answers the question as it was phrased

Comment: @user3293056 "gain" just means the operation $y(t) = g\cdot x(t), g\in \mathbb{R}$ It affects all signal properties the same way: peak-to-peak, ones sided peak, max, min, mean, RMS, all scale the same way (mostly).

Comment: what does it mean then that loop gain varies with frequency?

Answer (score 0):

[Audio feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_feedback) occurs when "[loop gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_gain)", which varies with the frequency of the input, reaches unity; there is then

> acoustical feedback at the frequency with the highest
> loop gain

Though it does not always occur at one frequency (I don't know why this is the case).

So "unity gain" does not mean the amplification involved in the feedback loop would leave peak to peak amplitude unchanged

Comment: I don't really know what I'm talking about, but I wanted an answer that answered the slightly confused question. Correct me if I'm wrong